# Pulling from a local docker image instead

Tags: image, docker, docker-compose

I have an app with a Dockerfile content that looks like

## Dockerfile

```
FROM SOME_NUMBERS.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE

COPY docker/app/bin/startup.sh /usr/bin/

CMD ["/usr/bin/startup.sh"]
```

I don't want to pull the image from amazon anymore instead I'd like to "pull" from the already-existing local image pulled the after the first `docker-compose up --build` command was ran.

When I do `docker images` I get

`SOME_NUMBERS.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_name   SOME_HEX_VALUE   SOMESHORT_HEX        2 days ago          1.54 GB` which means the image is local already. I understand this

> if the host has the image you want docker-compose to use on it it will use that image but if the host doesn't have it, it will go to docker hub or whatever you have setup in your config for registries

So I changed the Dockerfile content to this:

`FROM IMAGE_ID:SOME_HEX_VALUE` where `IMAGE_ID` is the image id of the repository I want when I do `docker images` but then I get `Service 'app' failed to build: repository SOMESHORT_HEX not found: does not exist or no pull access` and I'd like to know how to tell Docker to use the local image instead of trying to pull from the amazon url. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First pull the images from the remote repository in your local Docker engine:

```
docker pull SOME_NUMBERS.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE
```

Now, give the image a new local tag:

```
docker tag SOME_NUMBERS.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE my-image-name
```

Now you can simply refer to `my-image-name`, as in:

```
FROM my-image-name
```

Comment: To expand on this, `docker tag SOME_NUMBERS.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE` will overwrite a locally built `app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE`, and then building your local `app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE` will overwrite the retagged remote image. This is useful if you want to ensure that `app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE` is all you need to reference the image but want to toggle between your local build and a remotely hosted image.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```
FROM IMAGE_ID
```

Or, this is already ok:

```
FROM SOME_NUMBERS.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_name:SOME_HEX_VALUE
```

Where `SOME_HEX_VALUE` is the tag version (the second column in `docker images`). *Note that if the images is present in your computer, docker won't try to pull it again.*